# XSLT 1.0 Group and Sum by values

Tags: xml, xslt, sum

I'm trying to do a group by and sum. I have this xml:

```
<articles>
<group>
  <code>1000</code>
  <description>GROUP A</description>
  <article>
    <code>2600</code>
    <description>Article A</description>        
    <qty>14.00</qty>
    <amount>14.00</amount>        
    <menu_code>true</menu_code>
  </article>
  <article>
    <code>2600</code>
    <description>Article A</description>
    <qty>10.00</qty>
    <amount>0.00</amount>        
    <menu_code>true</menu_code>
  </article>
  <article>
    <code>2600</code>
    <description>Article A</description>
    <qty>1.00</qty>
    <amount>1.00</amount>        
    <menu_code>false</menu_code>
  </article>
</group>
<group>
  <code>2000</code>
  <description>GROUP B</description>
  <article>
    <code>2600</code>
    <description>Article B</description>        
    <qty>28.00</qty>
    <amount>28.00</amount>        
    <menu_code>true</menu_code>
  </article>
  <article>
    <code>2600</code>
    <description>Article B</description>
    <qty>10.00</qty>
    <amount>27.00</amount>        
    <menu_code>false</menu_code>
  </article>
  <article>
    <code>2600</code>
    <description>Article B</description>
    <qty>4.00</qty>
    <amount>8.00</amount>        
    <menu_code>false</menu_code>
  </article>
</group>
```

And with this data, I need to show something like this:

**GROUP A**

Article A    Qty: 24  Total: 14.00

Article A*   Qty: 1   Total: 1.00

**GROUP B**

Article B    Qty: 28  Total: 28.00

Article B*   Qty: 14  Total: 35.00

Showing the data ordered by Group (articles/group) 
and then show the articles description (article/description), quantity sum (sum(qty)), and total sum (sum(amount)). 
And if the article has (article/menu_code = true), show in another line, separated from false (*)

Hope you can help me, Thanks!

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 1.0, the grouping can be achieved by a technique known as [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

In your example, since the `<article>` values are to be grouped based on `<description>` and `<menu_code>`, a key needs to be defined which will be a combination of `<description>` and `<menu_code>`.

```
<xsl:key name="kArticle" match="article" use="concat(description, '|', menu_code)" />
```

The next step is to group the `<article>` nodes using the key and node id. This will select only the appropriately grouped nodes.

```
<xsl:template match="article[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kArticle', concat(description, '|', menu_code))[1])]">
```

The rest of the `<article>` nodes are to be left unprocessed.

```
<xsl:template match="article" />
```

Below are 2 different XSLT for XML output and HTML output respectively. The underlying grouping concept is the same and the changes are only to the way the output is displayed.

**XSLT - XML output**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="kArticle" match="article" use="concat(description, '|', menu_code)" />

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="article[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kArticle', concat(description, '|', menu_code))[1])]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="description" />
            <totalQty>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kArticle', concat(description, '|', menu_code))/qty)" />
            </totalQty>
            <totalAmount>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('kArticle', concat(description, '|', menu_code))/amount),'#.00')" />
            </totalAmount>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="article" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML Output

```
<articles>
    <group>
        <code>1000</code>
        <description>GROUP A</description>
        <article>
            <description>Article A</description>
            <totalQty>24</totalQty>
            <totalAmount>14.00</totalAmount>
        </article>
        <article>
            <description>Article A</description>
            <totalQty>1</totalQty>
            <totalAmount>1.00</totalAmount>
        </article>
    </group>
    <group>
        <code>2000</code>
        <description>GROUP B</description>
        <article>
            <description>Article B</description>
            <totalQty>28</totalQty>
            <totalAmount>28.00</totalAmount>
        </article>
        <article>
            <description>Article B</description>
            <totalQty>14</totalQty>
            <totalAmount>35.00</totalAmount>
        </article>
    </group>
</articles>
```

**XSLT - HTML Output**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="kArticle" match="article" use="concat(description, '|', menu_code)" />

    <xsl:template match="articles">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="group">
                    <h3><xsl:value-of select="description" /></h3>
                    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Article Description</th>
                            <th>Total Quantity</th>
                            <th>Total Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="article" />
                    </table>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="article[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kArticle', concat(description, '|', menu_code))[1])]">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="description" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kArticle', concat(description, '|', menu_code))/qty)" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('kArticle', concat(description, '|', menu_code))/amount),'#.00')" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="article" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

HTML Output

[image: HTML Tabular Output]